# Struts2 generates value="Submit" which the W3C markup validator says is an error

Tags: html, struts2, w3c-validation, html-input, struts-tags

I have the following `<s:submit>` tag code:

```
<s:submit action="shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList" 
          type="image" src="/llr/theme/delete.gif"
          onclick="clearDirtyFlag();deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList('%{organizationInfo.orgId}');"
          tabindex="16" />
```

which generates the following HTML:

```
<input type="image" 
       alt="Submit" 
       src="/llr/theme/delete.gif" 
       id="shipment_shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList" 
       name="action:shipment_deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList" 
       value="Submit"
       tabindex="16"
       onclick="clearDirtyFlag();deleteShipperFromChosenShipperViewList('1');"/>
```

The W3C Markup Validator ([W3C](https://validator.w3.org/)) marks the HTML as an error.  The error message is:

> Attribute`value` not allowed on element `input` at this point.

Evidently `value` is not an allowed attribute when the type is image. How do I keep Struts2 from generating the `value` attribute?

Comment: Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. This is not a bug in the HTML checker. The checker conforms to the spec in not allowing the `value` attribute in this case. If you go to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#image-button-state-(type=image) and scroll down to the **Bookkeeping details** section, you’ll see that it says, “The element's value attribute must be omitted.”.

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully someone can tell me how to keep `Struts2` from generating that attribute.

Comment: Create a jira issue for that - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW/.

Comment: It's not the issue, the validator says ok.

Comment: @RomanC Where do you see ok?

Comment: It's valid in HTML 4 because DTDs can't make an attribute forbidden only if another attribute has a specific value. HTML 5 doesn't use DTDs so it can mark it invalid.

Comment: @AleksandrM I've used W3C Validator, and this question doesn't relate to struts2

Comment: @RomanC — The question is asking how to prevent struts2 from generating a value attribute on an image input. It is entirely about struts2.

Comment: @Quentin The second question is asking to check the bug in the validator. Anyway it's off-topic because it's unclear what is actually asked.

Comment: @RomanC — The question is perfectly clear. "Is the validator right, if so, how do I fix my struts2 code to fix the HTML?". The comments have established that the validator **is** right, so it just comes down to "How do I fix it?". The part about the validator is just a reasonable check to make sure that the question isn't based on a false premise.

Comment: @Quentin No, OP didn't say "Is the validator right, if so, how do I fix it?". The comment did it but the question is not, OP is not sure about how validator is working, also OP is *not* asking to fix a bug in struts2 framework, he is asking to fix it in the validator.

Comment: @RomanC — No. "Evidently value is not an allowed attribute when the type is image. How do I keep Struts2 from generating the value attribute?" is very clearly asking how to prevent Structs2 from generating the value attribute. Then "Or is this a bug in the W3C Validator?" is just checking to see if it really is a bug (in Structs2) that needs fixing … which it is. Since it is, the first part of the question stands as the important part.

Comment: @Quentin No such framework Structs2, you just speculate on the first question and forget about second one. "a bug in the W3C Validator"

Comment: @RomanC — I didn't forget about it! I keep referring to it in my comments! There are two ways to answer this question. 1. "This is how you stop Struts2 from generating the value attribute" and 2. "It is a bug in the validator. Here is the section from the spec which supports that". The comments have established that 2 would be a wrong answer.

Comment: Since @sideshowbarker showed the Validator was correct I do need to know how to keep `Struts2` from generating the `value` attribute.  I created a jira as @Aleksandr recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the fixed version is released, you have a few options.

- Use plain HTML input tag `<input type="image" ...>` instead of `<s:submit>`. If you are using not `simple` theme then you also should put `<input>` into some HTML tags.
- Copy the `submit.ftl` from the struts2-core jar into your project and modify it.
- Just ignore this W3C Markup Validator error, there are probably worse things to worry about. :)